# Select Element By Text in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

This may sound so simple but why there is no method to find element by its 
inner text without using xpath?
for instance there is an element:

```
<button>Some Text</button>
```

and Selenium does not provide any methods to select it by inner text. 
Something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.innerText("Some Text");
```

What is the the other way to find element by inner text? 
I am well aware of xpath, but I can not use it because of restrictions of the project.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [`linkText`](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-link-text) method:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Some Text"))
```

You also have [`partialLinkText`](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-partial-link-text):

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Partial Text"))
```

For examples, see [how-to-locate-element-by-link-text-and-partial-link-text-locator](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/how-to-locate-element-by-link-text-and-partial-link-text-locator/)

Edit:
As @Cajova_Houba mentioned that **it works only for anchor elements `<a>`**

Comment: listed methods will select elements that has a tag, methods won't work for other elements

Comment: @NodirNasirov you are right! See the last line in the answer... This is a good question there for I have upvoted... I think you should suggest this feature to selenium via GitHub... As for my answer some stack overflow users may find it helpful... Henc my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use methods in XPath.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Some Text']"));
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: If you read the question, I said that I am well aware of xpath, and project has limitations, using xpath is prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works in java.

```
        WebElement chosenElement;
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));
        for(WebElement element:elements){
            if(element.getText().equals("Some Text")){
                chosenElement = element;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I confess I have never seen a page with 1000s of buttons but I will take your word they exist. I don't know how long it takes findElements to find all of the elements on the page but I think the java loop would handle several thousand items without a noticeable delay.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't seem to be possible for every element, according to [Selenium documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#locating-ui-elements-webelements). You can try to use

```
By.linkText("link text")
```

or

```
By.partialLinkText("partial link text")
```

But that works for anchor elements (`<a>`) only.

Comment: I know about linkText and partialLinkText, those methods are for links only, not for elements with other tags