# Issues finding elements in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

To preface, I know methods to find elements has been asked and done many times over, I've searched and tried for a few hours now. I'm trying to loop through a few buttons but I can't find the buttons with selenium. Here's the html I am working with

```
<button class="_0mzm- sqdOP  L3NKy       " 
type="button">Follow</button>
```

So far I've tried:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name(._0mzm-.sqdOP.L3NKy)
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(._0mzm-.sqdOP.L3NKy)
driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Follow')
```

My code currently is:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('._0mzm-.sqdOP.L3NKy')
sleep(3)
print(len(elements))
```

where the print returns 0

Where should I go from here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select Element By Text in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132715/select-element-by-text-in-selenium)

Comment: Please post the error so we can see what's happening.

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock Clarification at the end

Comment: You are missing a hyphen in your current code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @AndyG And that's the issue. Thanks. Sorry the waste of a question

Comment: @AustinPalmer If you feel the question wasn't a valid one you can click on the `delete` link under your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So things are working now?  If not, did you try

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button._0mzm-.sqdOP.L3NKy')
```

Are there really that many spaces in you class name?  Eg the 7 trailing spaces at the end of the class name?  That might make things difficult, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Yeah it works now sorry, I forgot the underscore. Also I took the spaces out at the end like you have above and it runs as intended, so I don't think it matters